# NLP techniques for converting from a direct speech to a reported speech

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

Any idea of some NLP techniques to transform a direct speech to a reported speech ?

Example converting : *"I'm learning NLP" said a user* to : *a user said he's learning NLP.*

I thought about paraphrasing but not sure..

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by reported speech? It might be easier to help out if you could elaborate on the end goal. What are you trying to do?

***EDIT***
I see so what you are looking to do is to translate between active and passive voice. When it comes to techniques to do this I found several options:

1. You can train a model using a long short-term memory (LSTM) recurrent neural networks (RNNs) model to detect whether it is an active or passive model. From there you can then work on the translation part. Example for model [here](https://www.bobbywlindsey.com/2021/01/09/how-to-detect-passive-and-active-voice-in-your-writing-using-an-lstm/) and translation [here](https://github.com/DanManN/pass2act).
2. It looks like you will need to familiarize yourself with the [Spacy python library](https://spacy.io/). An example of how this can be used in your case can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/armsp/30c2c1e19a0f1660944303cf079f831a).
3. Another, though more unorthodox approach is through the use of the program language Prolog. A paper on this subject can be found [here](https://deepai.org/publication/aandp-utilizing-prolog-for-converting-between-active-sentence-and-passive-sentence-with-three-steps-conversion) with the accompanying code [here](https://github.com/tqtrunghnvn/ActiveAndPassive).
4. [Here](https://www.rangakrish.com/index.php/2020/02/16/automatically-converting-active-voice-to-passive-voice-and-vice-versa/) is a short primer on using Prolog for your specific task.

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: @Yassine I have edited my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to fine tune a T5 & Bart model and looking up Spacy actually! I'll look up the other options you proposed :)